# Embedding shell scripts in another language?

Tags: c++, shell

Is it possible to embed shell scripts into a higher-level programming language, for example, C++? 
How would one go about doing that? For example, do you just place the script somewhere in the C++ code and the compiler is able to understand the script and the C++ code too?

Comment: What do you mean _embed_?

Comment: yes, it is possible. Though I think your question is rather *and if so, how?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you embed shell scripts into higher-level languages ?
>   Answer: Yes

You can always use the system api calls to execute any command and hence any shell script.

In C++, you can call the `system` function, like

```
#include<cstdlib>
system("myShellScrit.sh");
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @stevenScott you can accept the answer if it helped